# SQL - select all rows containing account number proceeding an earlier status

Tags: sql, sql-server

When an account reaches a specific status, I need to return the account number using a SELECT statement returning any rows with a later date for the same account regardless of the proceeding status.  My table and results will look a bit like this:[Table and expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m69n.png)

If I were to break down the result set by account number I would need it to look like this.  For account 001 the first time I see B2 I want to see all later rows regardless of status, earlier rows are to be ignored.  I have used this example because B2 is seen again later.  Rows 2,3,4 are returned.

For account 002, there is only one row to be displayed. Row 5 is returned:

For account 003 B2 is the first given status so no previous rows to exclude.  rows 6,7,8 are returned.

Comment: Can't you add expected result as a table too, instead of just the text?

Comment: I tried but, only allowed to embed one image as a first time poster.  Let me see if I can add the expected results as a text table.

Comment: The edit didn't work out to well the post reformats it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE date_time >= 
     (SELECT MIN(date_time) from YourTable p
     where t.account_number = p.account_number and p.status = 'B2')
```

I think this should do the trick, the WHERE clause filters only those account numbers that have status B2 and with dates after it.

Comment: Absolutely staggered by the speed of that response!!  A lot of people pondered long and hard over that.  It works perfectly.  Many thanks!!!